# Is it possible to create a ASP classic web service without using SOAP?

Tags: json, web-services, asp-classic

I need to create a Web Service in ASP classic(no choice unfortunately) but I need to do it using more modern standards like using JSON instead of SOAP. I'v been searching the web but I can't seem to find any way to do this. Is it even possible? and if it is can you please show me a tutorial or example.

Comment: ASP classic never had any capability to create web services, unless you did it from scratch, by yourself, with no help. Are you seriously not even permitted to install .NET?

Comment: You CAN create a REST API and consume REST data with ASP classic, it is possible though it may not be exactly what the original framework inventors intended (i.e. it may be a little hackish).  See my answer below with links to resources regarding that.

Comment: @Netizen: I did say, "unless you did it from scratch, by yourself, with no help"

Comment: @JohnSaunders but there are some classic ASP utilities people have made, such as JSON parsers, that you can use to piece together a solution.

Comment: @Netizen: compared to something like WCF, this constitutes "from scratch, by yourself, with no help"

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes, compared to WCF I suppose that could be considered "from scratch" you are correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I build a REST application using ASP Classic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147040/can-i-build-a-rest-application-using-asp-classic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few resources that may provide some of the information you need:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88556/how-to-make-classic-asp-interesting-if-you-are-stuck-with-it

[Calling REST web services from a classic asp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219/calling-rest-web-services-from-a-classic-asp-page)

[Can I build a REST application using ASP Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147040/can-i-build-a-rest-application-using-asp-classic)

ASP Classic example of REST / JSON call: https://gist.github.com/joseph-montanez/1948929

Answer (score 0):

My c# WebService Class has these Compiler Tags:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://myWebService/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

Since it was requested that the WebService can also communicate with JSON clients we added this Compiler Tag:

```
[ScriptService]
```

Methods are tagged with

```
[WebMethod] 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

It all works fine with SOAP clients and with JSON clients but the 
JSON Developers want to get Standard Status Codes in case the
WebService throws an Exception and I don't know how to
accomplish this.